# Extracting data in tabular form from camelcamelcamel

Tags: data-request, web-crawling, prices

[image]

Can anyone give me pointers on how I can extract price and sales rank data from [camelcamelcamel.com](http://camelcamelcamel.com)? They display only a chart showing the evolution of prices/sales rank over time, but I'm trying to extract the underlying data that generates this chart. I tried looking at the HTML, but can't find the relevant call based on which the chart is computed. Any help will be much appreciated!

(Disclaimer: This is related to a research project that I'm doing, and I don't seek to clone the website or to scrape it en masse in any way - I just need price data for a small set of products (1000 at max)).

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the networks tab of a sample page - I tried to see if any of these files potentially have the data, but can't find it at first glance, if anyone has any pointers that would be much appreciated!

Comment: this requires a log-in, which is the primary reason why this isn't open data, therefore i am flagging this for being closed for not following this site's rules around questions. i tried checking it out anyways to help, but the charts are behind a log-in and i'm not going to sign up. if you can provide a url/example, i'm happy to look into it for you. you can ping me at jalbertbowden - google's email service

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about open data.

Comment: Thanks @albert - the price data actually doesn't require a log in (although the sales rank data does - sorry for posting it here!). Here's a sample url that should display the price history chart without a log in: [camelcamelcamel.com/product](https://camelcamelcamel.com/SanDisk-Cruzer-Low-Profile-Drive-SDCZ33-004G-B35/product/B005FYNSPK?active=summary). If you have any pointers wrt extracting the underlying data, that would be awesome. Thanks and sorry again!

Answer (score 2):

As nearly as I can tell, the image is generated server-side (not HTML5 canvas or anything). A sample image:

https://charts.camelcamelcamel.com/us/B001444G5Q/amazon.png?force=1&zero=0&w=725&h=440&desired=false&legend=1&ilt=1&tp=all&fo=0&lang=en

In other words, the database and underlying data may not be available to end users at all.

You could try parsing the image itself, using a combination of OCR and looking for green (the decimal RGB values appear to be 99,168,164, identified by https://www.beautycolorcode.com/63a8a4 as "moderate cyan"), but that would be ugly.

You could also try contacting them directly.

Comment: Thanks @Barry Carter, I guess getting in touch with them would be the easiest thing to do at this point!

Comment: the data is definitely in the document...look @ the tables below the images. i just found this piece of the puzzle in network tab: https://us-ads.openx.net/w/1.0/acj?o=3916918993&callback=OX_3916918993&ju=https%3A//camelcamelcamel.com/SanDisk-Cruzer-Low-Profile-Drive-SDCZ33-004G-B35/product/B005FYNSPK%3Factive%3Dsummary&jr=&auid=537253288&dims=&adxy=&res=2560x1440x24&plg=pm&ch=UTF-8&tz=240&ws=0x0&ifr=1&tws=2540x630&nl=65%2C31&ul=69%2C35

Comment: hi albert, i had tried going through many entries in the network tab but couldn't find anything that potentially had the data - how do you suggest making use of the us-ads link you posted to try and get at the data?

Comment: idk man. actually i don't think the us ads is part of it..sorry